# How to check if a shortcode is being executed in a widget or post

Tags: shortcode, widgets

I am creating a feature for my website using a WordPress shortcode. The shortcode is displays an HTML table that contains certain data.

I have enabled the short code for widget/sidebar and it is working fine in the widget.

The only problem is that my designer has created two different styles; one for post and another for widget. Is there any way to know that the code is being executed in sidebar or in post?

eg:

```
if(is_widget()){
//add stylesheet for widget here
}
else{
//add stylesheet for post here
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Are the styles so significantly different that you couldn't just adjust it based on container size?

Comment: yes, in fact they are two different css files. for post the table have 4 columns and for widget it have 2 columns.

Comment: The Number of columns are just an example, even the icon used are different for widget and post.

Comment: Just brainstorming some ideas (I'm not sure if this is an option depending on who your end-user will be) but what about adding another attribute to your shortcode like `[myshortcode type="post"]` where `type` indicates if it's a "post" or "widget" format and then apply a style based on that attribute setting.

Comment: I appreciate your try, But I cannot use attribute as the end user will get confused. I will keep this as my last option.

Comment: That's an understandable concern. The wording could be modified to make it more like a feature though. Instead of "post/widget" it could be "full/mini" or something that suggests it's a display feature for the user.

Comment: Yes, If I you short-code's attribute then I will try to make it less confusing. Thanks for your Help

Comment: just add styles for both and use descendant selectors. widgets will be inside widget container elements, and posts will be inside posts container element.

Comment: Is the HTML output different, or just the styling? As long as the underlying HTML doesn't have to change, you don't need any PHP - you can use Milo's suggestion targeting widget container element for the widget version, and targeting post container element for the post version.

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional tag [in_the_loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_the_loop) inside your shortcode function may serve the purpose.

```
if( in_the_loop() ) {
    //add stylesheet for post/page here...
} else {
    //add stylesheet for widget here...
}
```